# <botocore.paginate.PageIterator object at 0x0000011CF0AC70C8> Is my paginator ill? What iam doing wrong?

Tags: python, pagination, boto3, aws-organizations

I can´t solve my annoying problem, here is my code

```
import boto3
org = boto3.client('organizations')

paginator = org.get_paginator('list_policies')
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Filter='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY', PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 100})
print(page_iterator)
```

I would like to see the result but I get the following

```
<botocore.paginate.PageIterator object at 0x0000011CF0AC70C8>
```

Has anyone an idea where iam stuck here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boto3 paginators are generator-like objects. This means they don't contain all elements at once in printable form, but will produce **next** element in sequence when called.

So in order to print its contents you need only small addition of a loop (or list comprehension) in your code:

```
page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Filter='SERVICE_CONTROL_POLICY', PaginationConfig={'MaxItems': 100})
for i in page_iterator:
    print(i)
```

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html

Comment: Thank you very much sir! that helped me.